# i need to subtracting from two count tables.. how to subtracting from row by row but it getting subtracting from all row?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select iname,icode,inpage,items 
from( (SELECT inid, COUNT(iid) - (select COUNT(iid) 
                                  From itemsd GROUP by iid ) AS items 
       FROM items 
       GROUP by inid) as item 
INNER JOIN (SELECT inid, iname,icode,inpage 
            FROM intype) AS itype ON item.inid = itype.inid)
```

Comment: Add an alias to the row source for the most outer query at least. Or move the parenthesis from the most end to correct place (after `as item`).

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to accomplish.